# Vim: Maintain the history of a file after it has been changed and reloaded

Tags: vim

If I'm editing a file in Vim, then some external program changes the file, Vim tells me:

```
W11: Warning: File "test.erl" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

If I `L`oad the file, though, all the undo history is lost.

Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: it appears that this is one of the new features in Vim 7.3: https://groups.google.com/group/vim_announce/browse_thread/thread/66c02efd1523554b

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.

There is a very useful patch available for the vim source code available [here](http://code.google.com/p/vim-undo-persistence/) that keeps the undo history after exiting vim and restarting.  However, I've just tried it and it seems to fail when the file is edited externally.  It might be worth contacting the author or reporting a bug on the patch website to see if this can be overcome.

Comment: Thanks for the vim-debug link... And I will ask about that on the lists - thanks.

Comment: Another useful link is http://repo.or.cz/w/vim_extended.git which has a few other interesting patches as well.

Answer (score 0):

G'day,

I'm not sure but does setting autoread, i.e. entering `:set autoread` leave the undo history for the file when it changes?

Hmmmm. I'm thinking probably not because the change history is maintained as line numbers and vim doesn't know if those line numbers are still relevant to the changed file.

BTW WTF are you editing a file that is being changed by external forces anyway? Sounds dangerous to me. (-:

Comment: by "external forces" hehe :-) I can't help myself thinking of Darth Vader editing a file remotely ...

Comment: nope, autoread actually is just the equivalent of pressing `L` for you automatically.

Comment: I don't know what David is trying to do, but I've run into this when, for example, I write a bash script.  I do my first version, try to run it, and realize I forgot to set the script as executable.  If I chmod u+x the script while the file is loaded in vim, vim will helpfully tell me the file has changed and offer to load it, even though only the flags have changed.  The same thing if you are using a source-control system that fiddles with the write-permission bits, like Perforce does.

Comment: Yup - that's it exactly, @cjhuitt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I used before Vim 7.3:

```
" :e usually clears undo history, so we don't really do :e any more.
" Instead we delete the contents of the buffer, then read the file in, which
" is an operation we can undo.  We must delete the top (empty) line also.

:map :e<Enter> :%d<Enter>:r<Enter>:0<Enter>dd
```

When you see the warning prompt, you would have to hit `o`k instead of `l`oad, and then perform the load yourself: `:e<Enter>`

There are two disadvantages (although I found the tradeoff acceptable):

- You lose the line you were on.  Your cursor is left sitting at the top of the file.
- Vim still thinks the buffer is out of sync with the file, so when you next save, you may need to do `:w!` instead of the normal `:w`, and you will need to hit `y` to confirm the overwrite.

Edit: There might be [a workaround for the second problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035854/force-vim-to-overwrite-external-changes).

Edit: The first problem could be addressed with a bit more scripting (see `:h line`.)

Answer (score -3):

I don't see how vim could keep track of something it didn't do.

So, as to the question, I would suggest - source control ... but that's probably not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Why not, though? If vim believes the file contains an `a`, then some write a `b` to the file, why should Vim be unable to undo that `b`?

Comment: And... Unless I setup some elaborate scheme to commit after every change in Vim... I don't see how source control would help.

Comment: And if somebody deletes or moves the file ? Why shouldn Vim be unable to undelete it/or move it back ? ... It's not that simple. Vim uses a buffer principle, i.e. it saves the contents of a file to a buffer during the editing phase. I believe that's why it gives you an option to load the file again (and why it doesn't lock the file). @David (2nd comment) - yes.

Comment: Maybe I should reiterate a little. If vim locked the file, I guess something like that could be possible. Then he would track all changes that happened to that file. But it doesn't. Vim makes a copy of a file for itself, and lets the file go (it is not locked). When you :w, it writes the copy (buffer) contents to a file. For it to track a file in that way, it would need to ... well, I gather you gather what I'm trying to say by now.

Comment: The file disappearing is one thing... But I'm not asking about that - I'm asking about a file which has been modified (ie, the contents have been changed).