# Vim: Only show “file has been changed” warning if content is different

Tags: vim

Is it possible to setup Vim so that it will only show:

```
WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!!
```

If the file is actually *different*, not just when the timestamp changes?

For example, I'll quite frequently background Vim (^Z), roll back to an older version of a file (eg, to run the test suite against it), revert back to the current version and `fg` Vim again… But I still get the “file has changed” warning because, even though the content is identical, the timestamp has changed.

Comment: Do you have the `autoread` option set?

Comment: No… I don't like that options because it means I loose my undo history without being warned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003020/vim-maintain-the-history-of-a-file-after-it-has-been-changed-and-reloaded (although… Oohh… It looks like this was fixed in 7.3 :D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try on vim 7.3

`:help timestamp`

It is said that
`When Vim notices the timestamp of a file has changed, and the file is being
edited in a buffer but has not changed, Vim checks if the contents of the file
is equal.  This is done by reading the file again (into a hidden buffer, which
is immediately deleted again) and comparing the text.  If the text is equal,
you will get no warning.`

So I guess that in your case, something has changed other than the file timestamp ( or there is a bug in Vim).

In my case, I often get that message when I check out files : they change from "read only" to "read write" even if their content has not changed.

So I guess that if the properties of a file are affected, it is considered "changed" even if the content is the same.