# force vim to overwrite external changes

Tags: vim, vi

I use Vim 7.4 (Mac OS) to edit and run Lua scripts. I've mapped a key in my .vimrc to save the current buffer and run an external script.

The key map in .vimrc:

```
map V :w!<CR> :!python "$HOME/tools/client/concli.py" --lua %<CR>
```

It works fine but every once in a while the files are 'touched' by Xcode (touch shell command). Then when I hit the mapped key vim warns me that the file has been changed externally and I have to confirm to write to it.

This is quite annoying since the files are often touched. How could I force vim to overwrite external changes without prompting? I tried 'w!' without success.

Thank you, Laurent

Comment: according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300253/vim-only-show-file-has-been-changed-warning-if-content-is-different the message should not be shown if only the timestamp has changed. I think there are real changes present that you're going to overwrite...

Comment: A little confused here. You have a file opened in Vim. Some outside application (XCode) made changes to the file. You want to revert to the previous state or for Vim to update the current buffer to the new file contents?

Comment: @eckes there's no actual changes. The files is just touched. I can reproduce the issue manually (vi file; touch file in another term; :w -> vim ask for saving). Maybe it has to do with the touch command.

Comment: @ldigas Xcode makes no changes but just touch the file. I want vim to ignore that and save the file without asking me.

Comment: @LaurentZubiaur - That is also a change, in a way. "set autoread" should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the overwrite confirmation cannot be turned off with `:w!`, and `:set autoread` doesn't help in this case, neither. What does work is instructing Vim to explicitly check for changes before the write:

```
:checktime | w
```

Comment: It works if I explicitly enter the command in vim but fails if it's defined in the map command (.vimrc): map V :checktime \| w<CR> ... (I had to escape the pipe char)

Comment: That map works for me, and I see no reason why it shouldn't. You could try a custom `:command V checktime|w`.

Comment: Thanks it works! I don't know why I had to use a command and pipe the shell command as well `command V checktime | w | !python "$HOME/tools/client/concli.py" --lua %` and then `map <leader>r :V<CR>`

Comment: This appears to work fine if the buffer and file are identical, but if I have made changes to the buffer, I still get the annoying message.  Is there a more forceful workaround?  (I am getting desperate enough to consider deleting the file before every write!)

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
set autoread
```

should do it. It tells Vim to automatically re-reads the file changed outside Vim.

Comment: @LaurentZubiaur - Has anything changed in any way? I find it working on this side.

Comment: yes thanks. I had to use `checktime | w` as a command. Please see my comment to @IngoKarkat.

Comment: @LaurentZubiaur - In any case, glad to hear you sorted it out.

Comment: When `autoread` triggers: If I use GVim, `autoread` checks the file every time I unfocus and then refocus the GVim window. But with vim running in a terminal, `autoread` only seems to check the file if I change buffer and then change back again (`:bn :bp`), or if I run `:checktime`.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this in a mailing list.  Apparently it is called if the file has changed timestamp, after a call to an external shell command.

```
function! ProcessFileChangedShell()
    if v:fcs_reason == 'mode' || v:fcs_reason == 'time'
        let v:fcs_choice = ''
    else
        let v:fcs_choice = 'ask'
    endif
endfunction

autocmd FileChangedShell call ProcessFileChangedShell()
```

But it did not consistently fire for me.  (Depending whether or not I had edited the file since the change, which in my case was external.)

There are [some more tricks on the VimTips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Suppressing_file_changed_warnings_in_a_specific_buffer) which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set autoread
nnoremap <C-u> :checktime<CR>
```

Now whenever you want vim to reload external changes, just click `CTRL-U` :)